# Unicode encode error while uploading python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a python pandas dataframe that reads a csv or excel file like this:

```
if fileType == 'csv':
            df = pd.read_csv( templateFilePath, converters=converters )
        else:
            df = pd.read_excel( templateFilePath, sheetname=sheetName, converters=converters )

        df.fillna( '', inplace=True )
```

In one of the files that I'm trying to upload, it has value: `Banque des RÃƒÂ¨glements Internationaux (BRI) - BÃƒÂ¢le / Bank for International Settlements`

And I keep getting this error because of this: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 12-15: ordinal not in range(128)`

How do I fix this?

UPDATE:

Doing it like this:

```
        if fileType == 'csv':
            df = pd.read_csv( templateFilePath, converters=converters )
        else:
            df = pd.read_excel( templateFilePath, sheetname=sheetName, converters=converters )

        df.fillna( '', inplace=True )
       # for col in colNames:
        df['COUNTRY_NAME']=df['COUNTRY_NAME'].map(lambda x: x.encode('unicode-escape').decode('utf-8'))
```

And it fixed the error that was coming while uploading the file. But I don't want to specify any column name (like here I'm specifying 'country_name') because unicode can be present in any column. How do I do that?

Comment: #-*-coding:utf-8-*- in first line ?

Answer (score 0):

I have run into `UnicodeEncodeError` and used `encoding=latin-1` to fix the code:

```
if fileType == 'csv':
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv( templateFilePath, converters=converters )
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        df = pd.read_csv( templateFilePath, converters=converters, encoding='latin-1' )
```

Edit:

I don't think this question makes sense anymore. In any case here is an answer to your other (seemingly unrelated) question:

```
def re_encode(x):
    try:
        x_ = x.encode('unicode-escape').decode('utf-8')
    except:
        x_ = x
    return x_

df = df.applymap(re_encode)
```

Comment: No, it's not working. What's working is this: df['COUNTRY_NAME']=df['COUNTRY_NAME'].map(lambda x: x.encode('unicode-escape').decode('utf-8')), but I don't want to hard code column name, can't it check all columns?

Comment: So this means you were able to load the data?

Comment: Using: df['COUNTRY_NAME']=df['COUNTRY_NAME'].map(lambda x: x.encode('unicode-escape').decode('utf-8')) I was able to. Because right now unicode is only present in 'Country_Name' column, but it could be present in other columns as well, so I don't want to hard code any column.

Comment: But making a call like that implies that you have loaded the data into a `df` object already. Whereas your initial error was raised when trying to create the df. Or was this not the case?